# Place scss .map file in different folder in Intellij IDEA

Tags: css, intellij-idea, sass

I have a styles folder in my project. Inside it I have the following folders: css, scss, css-maps. I want the following: when I update a scss file in scss folder, I want it to create/update a css file with the same name in css folder and *.css.map file in css-maps folder.

```
|styles
    |css
        my-style.css
    |css-maps
        my-style.css.map
    |scss
        my-style.scss
```

I defined a SCSS watcher in my Intellij. It has the following settings:

```
Arguments: --no-cache --update $FileName$:../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css --no-cache --update $FileName$:../css-maps/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map

Working directory: $FileDir$

Output paths to refresh: ../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:../css-maps/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```

The problem is that it still outputs `my-style.css.map` to my css folder (and CSS file points to this map file), while in my css-maps folder it puts 2 files: `my-style.css.map` which looks exactly like the .css output file, and my-style.css.map.map. Yes, with double .map extension.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Here is configuration I'm using, hope it will help:
[image]
Arguments: --sourcemap=none --no-cache --update $FileName$:../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it didn't. Got this message: `DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing --sourcemap without a value is deprecated.
Sourcemaps are now generated by default, so this flag has no effect.
OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: -ource-map-url=../css-maps/my-style.css.map
  Use --trace for backtrace.
`

Comment: @Igal, one of arguments is "--sourcemap=none". It has a value, so  "Passing --sourcemap without a value is deprecated" is really strange. Can you post a screenshot of your config page?    
And "invalid option: "-ource-map-url" - this is also strange, it looks like a typo in "source-map-url"... but this parameter is not used by me.

Comment: I removed any other arguments that I had, so now I'm left only with yours. Now it doesn't output the .map file at all. Here's a screenshot of my settings: [link](http://oi68.tinypic.com/fp1bb5.jpg)

Comment: @Igal, I checked [link](https://github.com/sass/sass).
And it seems that custom path for sourcemap is not supported by the compiler:
[link](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/63586f1e51c0aec47a7afcc8cd17aa03f32f0a29/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb#L55)
[link](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/63586f1e51c0aec47a7afcc8cd17aa03f32f0a29/lib/sass/util.rb#L1073)

Comment: I see... That's a shame, really. Hopefully it will be resolved soon. Still, thank you very much!